# Integrate Cruise Control .NET with TFS

Tags: build-process, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to use Cruise Control .NET with TFS. What is the best way to integrate TFS with the latest version of Cruise Control .NET?

Comment: Have you considered using http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/ instead? We spent weeks working with CC, including doing the TFS Plugin fix mentioned below. We got it working, but maintaining CC is a very manual process (often involving editing XML). TeamCity is mostly point-and-click. This lowers the learning curve for all the developers involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin for cruise control.net that used to work.

[TFS Plugin from codeplex](http://tfsccnetplugin.codeplex.com/)

However, the code hasn't had an update in a couple years and the newer versions of cc.net use a different version of the NetReflector.dll.

In order to get this to work you need to:

-Download the tfs for cc.net plugin source from: 
[source on codeplex](http://tfsccnetplugin.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx)

-Open solution in VS 2008

-Delete the NetReflector.dll in the solution.

-Add the NetReflector.dll from the cc.net server path
    IE: C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server

-Rebuild the solution

-Drop the new dll into your cruise control app

-Restart cc.net

-Follow the configuration steps to setup the project block:

[configuration steps](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Visual+Studio+Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin)

And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.5, which was just CTP'd this week the TFS functionality is in the base package and there is no need for the plugin. Everything up until 1.5 Bryan has explained.

Comment: They are up to 1.6 now, and still no support for the overwrite option as far as I can tell.